# Apache multiple ports HTTPS

Tags: apache, https, proxy, bitnami

#### My config

- AWS Lightsail using Bitnami
- React running on the port 3000
- Express running on the port 3001
- HTTPS using the Bitnami script (using Let's encrypt)

#### What I would like

1. Any call from https://www.ipos.fun/ or https://ipos.fun/ or [ipos.fun/](https://www.ipos.fun/) or [www.ipos.fun/](https://www.ipos.fun/) to go to https://www.ipos.fun/. (adding wwww + https)
2. My Express API on the port 3001 to be also fine with HTTPS.

#### What is currently working

1. All frontend redirection work fine.

#### What is not working

2. My Express API works over HTTP but I have the error `www.ipos.fun unexpectedly closed the connection.` when I try to access https://www.ipos.fun:3001/.

#### What I tried

Please find all my config down below, but I think the important point is:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

I would like to have a matching based on port number, but nothing seems to work.
I also tried the following with the url https://www.ipos.fun:3001/api/

```
ProxyPass /api http://localhost:3001/
ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:3001/
```

I tried to create multiple `VirtualHost` to do a pattern matching on the port number, but it doesn't work.

#### Question

How do I make my Express API on the port 3001 HTTPS compliant?

Here is my config:

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>


<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  # BEGIN: Enable HTTP to HTTPS redirection
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  # END: Enable HTTP to HTTPS redirection
  # BEGIN: Enable non-www to www redirection
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
  # END: Enable non-www to www redirection
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "..."
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  # BEGIN: Enable non-www to www redirection
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
  # END: Enable non-www to www redirection
  SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/ipos.fun.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/ipos.fun.key"

  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>


    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/


  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Bitnami applications that uses virtual host configuration
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add the routing in the VirtualHost: 443,

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:3001/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:3001/
```

It is what I mentioned before, I was just testing on the port 3001 instead of the port HTTPS 443.